# When to use Spring OAuth2 vs Cloud Foundry UAA?

Tags: spring-security, cloud-foundry, spring-oauth2, cloudfoundry-uaa

Both code bases can provided OAuth2 capabilities. Why should I use one vs the other?

Answer (score 1):

The Spring OAuth2 library has capabilities of turning an application into a full-fledged OAuth2 Authorization Server, which is able to issue its own tokens **BUT** it still needs and depends upon a central OAuth2 provider for authentication. CF UAA is one such provider.

Facebook or Github are the other such OAuth2 service providers used more commonly for this purpose.

More details about Spring OAuth can be found at - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

I hope it helps.